# Moving applications to SD card

Tags: applications, rooting, 4.1-jelly-bean, external-sd

I own a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 (GT8010-Wifi) model and I would like to move some of my apps to the external SD card and change the default installation location to be the external SD card from now on. The Android version on the tablet PC is 4.1.2 and I have rooted it following a guide on the internet which can be accessed via the following URL: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv8440QhHsw
I would be happy to get some assistance on this matter, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android SDK. Instructions at http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-install-apps-onto-your-SD-Card-No-Root/?ALLSTEPS

Comment: Thanks, I tried the method described in that site but it did not work.

Comment: Whilst a link theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. @Vesnog what exactly is wrong? What didn't work, what is the error (if any)?

Comment: @RossC Thanks for the comment. The part that did not work is that after I change the storage location for applications through `adb` it downloads the application, but is not able to install it and display a message telling that the storage is insufficient.

Comment: @Vesnog do you have enough storage space at the moment? Maybe clear some out and try again? Delete caches etc? Uninstall some apps?

Comment: @RossC Actually, I have nearly 35 GB of free space on the SD card and 10 GB of free space on the internal memory.